# How to use the sum function in a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, integral

[image]

We want to calculate the value of an integral in linear plot.
For a better understanding look at the photo. Let's say the overall area is 1. We want to find what the value in a certain part is. For instance we want to know how much % of the overall 100% lay within the 10th and 11th month if everything refers to months and A as maximum stands for 24.
We can calculate a integral and then should be able to get the searched area by F(x) - F(x-1)
I thoght about the following code:

```
a <- 24
tab <-matrix(0,a,1)
tab <-cbind(seq(1,a),tab)
tab<-data.frame(tab)

#initialization for first point
tab[1,2] <- (2*tab[1,1] / a - tab[1,1]^2 / a^2)

#for loop for calculation of integral of each point - integral until to the area
for(i in 2:nrow(tab))
{tab[i,2] <- (2*tab[i,1] / a - tab[i,1]^2/ a^2) - sum(tab[1,2]:tab[i-1,2])}
#plotting
plot(tab[,2], type="l")
```

If you see the plot - it's confusing. Any ideas how to handle this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base R function `integrate()` can do this for you:

```
f <- function(x, A) 2/A - x / A^2

integrate(function(x)f(x, 24), lower=10, upper=11)

0.06510417 with absolute error < 7.2e-16
```

Comment: It's not a standard error, but an indication of the numeric error introduced by the numeric integration.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formulas directly:

```
a <- 24                          # number of divisions
x <- c(seq(1,a))                 # 
y <- x*2/a - x^2/a^2             # F(x)
z <- (x*2/a - x^2/a^2) - ((x-1)*2/a - (x-1)^2/a^2) # F(x) - F(x-1)
```

Then do the binding afterward.

```
> sum(z)
[1] 1
```